# Capturing 'Next' button pressed even in ionic/cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, android-keypad

I'm working with cross-platform apps using ionic/cordova. I'm stuck on a point where I want to disable certain functionality when 'Next' button on android keyboard is pressed. The problem is I'm unable to capture the event when 'Next' button is pressed through keyUp or keyPresses events. I've searched the web but couldn't fine any proper solution particular to my problem. 
I'm using following code to capture keyup etc events.

```
 setTimeout(() => {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', this.nextButtonHandler);
}, 10); 

nextButtonHandler(e) {
    //capture e.keyCode;
}
```

I've also tried catching this event by calling keyUp on ion-inout like following

```
 (keyup)="keyUp($event)"
```

but nothing seems to happen when I press 'Next' button while these functions works fine when I press other keys on android keyboard.
Am I missing something or do I need any special plugin of cordova to capture 'Next' button input ? 
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get keycode on every device using @HostListener. Keyup/keydown doesn't return keycode on android, while work fine on ios while @HostListener works great with all of them.
Here is the code to be used

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
docs(event) {
console.log(event.target.id);
console.log(event.keyCode)}
```

Just write this code in you .ts file and write in your textarea and you are good to go

Comment: Wow that actually works.  Thanks.  Bit of a hack though.  Would be good if it just worked correctly.

Comment: Yeah, i was also hoping for some easier thing without hack, but it is like this.. :)

Comment: This actually seems to work on Android if you put it on the ion-input: (keyup.enter)="onSubmit()"